# Adding a houdini paintworklet in a nuxt3/vue app

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, houdini, nuxtjs3

I am trying to add a paintworklet to my application, but I am having a really hard time.

The worklet is a npm dependency, but worklets can't be inlined, they need to be registered like so:

```js
CSS.paintWorklet.addModule('url/to/module.js');
```

I am having a hard time, because even though that currently works in my application, I am not sure if this is the right way to go about it, or if it will work in production. Currently, my url points to a file inside `node_modules` and I am not sure if nuxt will do anything with this.

I am currently doing this with a `.client.js` file inside the plugins folder. But they need an `export default function()`, but the worklet code does not have an export.

What I am currently trying to do, is tell nuxt somehow to grab certain files from `node_modules` and serve them as assets somehow, and then reference them some other way. But I cannot find any resources on this.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file path is specified in a literal string, containing `node_modules`, the paint worklet might appear to work in development mode, but the worklet file will *not* be bundled in the build output:

```js
CSS.paintWorklet.addModule('./node_modules/extra-scalloped-border/worklet.js')
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                           ❌ file not bundled in build output
```

#### Solution: Import the file

Importing a file enables the bundler to track the file, and include it in the build output. Nuxt 3 uses Vite by default, and the [Vite docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#explicit-url-imports) describe how to import the file to use with paint worklets:

> #### Explicit URL Imports
>
> Assets that are not included in the internal list or in `assetsInclude`, can be explicitly imported as an URL using the `?url` suffix. This is useful, for example, to import [Houdini Paint Worklets](https://houdini.how/usage).
>
> ```js
> import workletURL from 'extra-scalloped-border/worklet.js?url'
> CSS.paintWorklet.addModule(workletURL)
> ```

Since the [`CSS.paintWorklet` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PaintWorklet) is only available in the browser, make sure to use this in the `mounted()` hook, which only occurs client-side:

```js
import workletURL from 'extra-scalloped-border/worklet.js?url'

export default {
  mounted() {
    CSS.paintWorklet.addModule(workletURL)
  }
}
```

[demo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/nuxt3-paint-worklet-demo)

Comment: how would one also include a polyfill for houdini for firefox?

Comment: Polyfills are normally added via Vite configuration. What polyfill are you using exactly? I recommend posting a new question (with specific details to the problem and reproduction steps) so that someone familiar with the topic could provide an answer. I'll chime in if I can.